# deck.gl transitions and filtering

Tags: d3.js, deck.gl

Can anyone explain how data updates and transitions work with Deck.gl compared to d3js? For instance in this code:

```
var updateLayers = function(dataset) {
var scatterplot = new deck.ScatterplotLayer({
    /* unique id of this layer */
    id: 'checkins',
    /* data: an array of objects */
    data: dataset,
    /* data accessors */
    getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates, // returns longitude, latitude, [altitude]
    getRadius: d => circleSize(d.properties.reviews), // returns radius in meters
    getColor: d => [255, 0, 0],
    outline: true, // returns R, G, B, [A] in 0-255 range
    transitions: {
        getRadius: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: d3.easeCubicInOut,
            enter: value => [value[0], value[1], value[2], 1] // fade in
        }
    }
})

// Add the layer to deckgl:
deckgl.setProps({ layers: [scatterplot] });
}
```

It's unclear to me what `enter: value => [value[0], value[1], value[2], 1]` is doing. Can anyone explain? I would generally expect (per d3js) that this `enter:` is setting the breakpoints in the transition, but I'm unclear what `value` refers to?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/docs/api-reference/layer.md

> enter - Function - APPEARANCE (value => value) - Callback to get the value that the entering vertices are transitioning from.
>
> enter should return the value to transition from. for the current vertex.
>
> It receives two arguments:
>
> toValue (TypedArray) - the new value to transition to, for the current vertex
>
> fromChunk (Array | TypedArray) - the existing value to transition from, for the chunk that the current vertex belongs to. A "chunk" is a group of vertices that help the callback determine the context of this transition. For most layers, all objects are in one chunk. For PathLayer and PolygonLayer, each path/polygon is a chunk.

Comment: Yes I've seen this, but am unclear what it means in relationship to the example above. eg: is "value[0], value[1], and value[2]" the toValue or the fromChunk?

Comment: @Brad: callback has only one argument so `value` == `toValue`, most likely it just animates the opacity and not the position.